# Delete all lines until line that starts with dashes

Tags: vim

I use Vim to edit my e-mails and what I do like hundred times a day is to delete all the quoted lines until my signature starts:

```
Some my text and the caret _

> Some other quoted text I want to get rid of
> Blah blah

--
My signature
```

What I always do is <kbd>jVjjjjjjd</kbd> or something similar.

I would like to be more efficient in this and delete everything until the double dashes. Unfortunately <kbd>df-</kbd> works only on the current line and I would like to specify regexp like "^--".

How to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about `d/^--`? (That is, delete everything from the caret position until the first hit of a search for "--" at the start of a line.)

Comment: Thanks all. I like this solution because it's plain Vim. I will bind this to a leader-key.

Comment: Just in case: :map <leader>d d/^--<ESC>:noh<CR>

Answer (score 3):

My [mail_movement plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3182) defines motions to go to quoted blocks and corresponding text objects. With it, deleting a quoted block is as simple as `daq` (delete a quote).